# Back button on windows phone(HTML app)

Tags: javascript, html, button, back

So I have searched all the forums and guides over the internet and I could not find the answer for my problem.

All I want is to use the back button on windows phone(hardware button, not appbar button) to go back to index.html.

Ex: index -> page1 -> (press back button) -> index -> (press back button) -> exit app.

Comment: does the button trigger a keypress event? if it does then would be same as handle for any other key press

Comment: That seems like it would require you to have access to the underlying phone hardware which is not possible from a web app unless it is wrapped/built in something like [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) where Windows Phone is [not fully supported as of yet](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-side-menu-doesnt-work-on-windows-phone-8/6024).

Comment: So it can't be done? What about javascript?

Comment: I can think of possibly using a complicated script that, instead of watching for the back button press, watches for the browser *navigating back* - our website uses that for some complex forms as a soft-blocker for users on the Desktop. That said, the amount of fiddling you'd have to do would almost amount to hacking, and kind of rubs against my feelings of "Provide a consistent user experience." MS decided that pressing Back in IE11 should navigate Back. Don't interrupt that design, or **it will only confuse users**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate a hardware button object then listen for the 'backpressed' event. There is a property on the event 'handled' that you can set to alert the system that you've captured the back button press and don't want the system to do anything else.

The documentation for this event can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.backpressed.aspx

```
var hardwareButtons = Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons;
hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", function (e) {
   // Navigate back in your webview. 
   e.handled = true; // Notifies OS that you've handled the back button event.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He may be talking about the other use of the term "app" - a high-functioning, complex website in mobile IE 11. In which case, I don't think that would be available.